# How to find duplicate documents and filter elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with the following structure:

```json
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("44b378cb66b323427311d3da"),
        "person" : "person1",
        "course" : "courseA",
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("44b378cb66b323427311d3db"),
        "person" : "person1",
        "course" : "courseA",
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("44b378cb66b323427311d3dc"),
        "person" : "person1",
        "course" : "courseB",
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("44b378cb66b323427311d3dd"),
        "person" : "person1",
        "course" : "courseC",
}
```

I need to find the duplicates entries for the "person" field, but I need to filter those values using the "course" value.

This is the code that is returning all the duplicate fields, I tried to add a new value in the match clause to filter by "course" but it didn't work and no value was returned.

```js
db.getCollection('students').aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: { person: "$person"},
    uniqueIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  }}, 
  { $match: {
    count: { $gte: 2 },
  }},
  { $sort : { count : -1} }
]);
```

I just need, the duplicates `person:"Person1"` that has `course: "courseA"`.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. what do you mean by *need to filter those values using the "course" value*? Can you share expected input/output?

Comment: I want to find all the duplicates ("persons"), but I want to retrieve only the ones that match the value that I want in the "course" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just collecting person IDs in the `group` stage, instead you need to collect to person ID and course and then filter on it. You will need filtering using multiple `match`

```
db.getCollection('duptemp').aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: '$person', persons: {$addToSet: '$$ROOT'}, count: {$sum:1}}},
  {$match: {count: {$gt:1}}},
  {$unwind: '$persons'},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$persons'}},
  {$match: {course : 'course name'}}
])
```